# Tesseract Number Recognition from image

Tags: ocr, tesseract

```
tesseract ../spliced-time.png spliced-time -l eng --psm 13 --oem 3 txt pdf hocr
```

Gives me a result of: Al

I am confused if there is more I should be doing, or what would be the best approach for an image like this where the font and alignment should be generally the same. Just the numbers would be different. I was looking at opencv as well, but I feel as though this image shouldnt be that hard with maybe some extra work, or configuration or training to recognize the numbers well.

Image Attachment:[image]

Comment: Try inverting colors

Comment: @DmitriiZ. ah yeah I had done a regular invert, but didn't invert from white to black there, cause this was a colored image originally, I will see if that makes it any better.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. So that gives me a result of 1:18 so clearly better, is there any other things I should or can do to make it more accurate?

Comment: Yeah, you can try [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#erosion)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. Kk I will try that as well and let you know the results. This should help with words providing the same issue right, same font btw.

Comment: Haven't seen other symbols of this font, but for the ones which you showed erosion should help